# Script to Search String and copy file(s) to another location

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, copy, find

I need to basically match files from one folder to folders on a network based on the string of the file name.

The similarity in the file name will provide the destination folder that I need to copy the file from the source folder to.

So Example:

Folder on c:\

C:\Testfile

has a number of files that start with Cxxxxxx (these files are either pdf, JPG, xls or doc)

I need to then copy the file from this location using the string of the name starting with Cxxxxxx

To a folder on the network location:

Network location:

\mydomain\myshare\archive\

the archive folder has many sub folders so i need to search the archive folder for the same string file name Cxxxxx once that file is found i need to copy the file from C:\Testfile to the found location.

How i do this manually:

I go into folder C:\Testfile I copy the file name C100001

I then goto the network share:

\mydomain\myshare\archive\

And perform a search for C100001

From the result i open up the location

\mydomain\myshare\archive\2015\may\company\

and paste the file C100001 to that location

Unfortunately i have to do this with every file in c:\Testfile so a script to help with this would be greatly appropriated.

I tried a simple code with batch file to find and copy an exact file from one location to another:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d C:\Testfile\textfile.txt') do copy /b "%%~i" "C:\Testfile\Test 2"
```

Comment: This is far to broad a question for S/O; starting point; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: What did you tried as code so far ? i think you can do this with batch file too with the command [Where.exe](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)

Comment: I tried a simple code to find and copy an exact file from one location to another: for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d C:\Testfile\textfile.txt') do copy /b "%%~i" "C:\Testfile\Test 2"

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch that can accept wildcards with the command **Where.exe** as string input :

[image]

```
@echo off
Mode con cols=75 lines=5 & color 0A
echo(
Set /p "Location=Enter the folder location where do you want to serach> "
cls & echo(
echo You chose this location "%Location%"
echo(
Set /p "FileName=Enter the file name to looking for> "
Mode con cols=90 lines=11
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
echo( & cls
echo(  & echo  Please Wait for moment .... Searching for "%FileName%" on "%Location%"
where /R "%Location%" "%FileName%" > %SearchResult%
Set Destination=e:\TestCopyDestination
For /f %%a "delims=*" in (%SearchResult%) Do (echo copy "%%a" "%Destination%" & Copy "%%a" "%Destination%")
pause
start %SearchResult%
```

**Edit : 17/06/2015 at 23:20**

Try this second batch :

```
@echo off
set Location=c:\TestFile
Set Destination=c:\TestFile\Test 2
Set FileName=*.*
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
Where /R "%Location%" "%FileName%" > %SearchResult%
For /f "delims=*" %%a in (%SearchResult%) Do (If Not Exist "%Destination%\%%~na" MD "%Destination%\%%~na")
For /f "delims=*" %%b in (%SearchResult%) Do (echo Copy "%%b" "%Destination%\%%~nb" & Copy /-Y "%%b" "%Destination%\%%~nb")
pause
Explorer "%Destination%"
```

Comment: Great that helps alot as now I have a txt file which shows me where the files are located across the network. Now I need to extract that data to perform the copy operation

Comment: If you get the text file, you need only to change the destination variable to your UNC path (Network) and the script can do the rest !

Comment: Ok so i get the results but the files do not get copied to the location: As a test I changed the destination as you said:

Comment: <blink> Set Destination="C:\Testfile\Test 2\"
For /f %%a in (%SearchResult%) Do (echo copy "%%a" "%Destination%" & Copy "%%a" "%Destination%")
pause
start %SearchResult% </blink>

Comment: The SerachReuslts.txt file has the following   C:\Testfile\CN101.JPG
C:\Testfile\CN101.pdf
C:\Testfile\CN101.xls
C:\Testfile\CN102.pdf
C:\Testfile\CN103.pdf
C:\Testfile\M101 - Copy.txt
C:\Testfile\M101.pdf
C:\Testfile\New Text Document.bat
C:\Testfile\SearchResult.txt
C:\Testfile\Testbatch.bat
C:\Testfile\textfile.txt
C:\Testfile\Test 2\textfile.txt
C:\Testfile\Test 2\Company\CN101.txt
C:\Testfile\Test 2\Company\DHL\CN102.pdf
C:\Testfile\Test 2\Company\Statment\M101.pdf

Comment: You should remove the quotes in variable Destination=C:\Testfile\Test 2\ because you use it in command for loop "%Destination%"

Comment: That works in copying to the selected destination, i need to find a way so that the source file matches the location of the destination file to copy to that particular folder. So file CN101 in the location C:\Testfile\ will then get copied over to C:\Testfile\Test 2\Company\ (where there is already a file with the same name (CN101.txt)

Comment: Check my edit and tell me if this what you want or not ?

Comment: Hi Hackoo, this is close but I do not need the folder to be called the same as the file name. I need to search in sub folders from C:\Testfile\Test 2\ to find if a similar file name exists and then copy the file (with the similar name) from C:\Testfile\ to that relevant folder

Comment: Hi Hackoo, I could send you a documented example of what i need to achieve with screenshots if that helps?